# bash script treats string as command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I have a noobish problem with a bash script.
It treats a string as command.

Script is

```
 #!/bin/bash
 if ["$(pidof whatever)"]
 then
  echo "suicide"
 fi
 exit 0
```

The error I get at run is "[29999] command is not found".

Ty for your help and time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a space between `[` and `$`. `[` is test command.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 if [ $(pidof whatever) ]
 then
  echo "suicide"
 fi
 exit 0
```

Answer (score 3):

`[` is a command. Just like with any other command, `bash` expects the command to be followed by a space, then the first argument, then another space, etc. Here is the correct way:

```
if [ "$(pidof whatever)" ]; then ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem seems to be lack of space between the test operators. Try:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 if [ "$(pidof whatever)" ]
 then
  echo "suicide"
 fi
 exit 0
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need spaces between the [ and ]
e.g.

```
if [ $(pidof whatever) ]
```

or

```
if [ "$(pidof whatever)" ]
```

Comment: It's the spaces around the square brackets not the quotes that's causing the error message.